# GHC cannot find module in cabal sandbox

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, cabal-install

I am using Haskell version 7.8.4 on (X)Ubuntu 15.10, with Cabal-Install 1.18 both installed through `apt`. I have not attempted to install anything Haskell-related by hand on this machine. I set up a cabal sandbox, fetched and installed a module only to discover that `ghc` doesn't seem to be picking it up. `ghc -v` seems to suggest that I have two versions of the cabal library that are mutually shadowing each other. How does this work?

I am starting out with an empty directory `/tmp/haskell-example`

then I do a `cabal sandbox init`.

```
$ cabal sandbox init
Writing a default package environment file to
/tmp/haskell-example/cabal.sandbox.config
Creating a new sandbox at /tmp/haskell-example/.cabal-sandbox
```

then I install `natural-numbers` because I want to use the `Data.Natural` module in a program. This operation succeeds.

```
$ cabal install natural-numbers
Resolving dependencies...
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at
/tmp/haskell-example/.cabal-sandbox
Configuring natural-numbers-0.1.2.0...
Building natural-numbers-0.1.2.0...
Installed natural-numbers-0.1.2.0
```

I can verify that the `Data.Natural` module has indeed been installed to the cabal sandbox.

```
$ ls /tmp/haskell-example/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.4/natural-numbers-0.1.2.0
 Data
libHSnatural-numbers-0.1.2.0.a
libHSnatural-numbers-0.1.2.0-ghc7.8.4.so
$ ls /tmp/haskell-example/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.4/natural-numbers-0.1.2.0/Data
Natural.dyn_hi
Natural.hi
```

then I create a simple `Main.hs` file that imports `Data.Natural` but does not use it.

```
module Main where

import Data.Natural

main = putStrLn "Hello World"
```

When I try to `ghc Main.hs` I see the following :

```
$ ghc Main.hs 
Main.hs:3:8:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Natural’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

With the verbose flag enabled, it seems as if my cabal is getting shadowed by a later cabal, which is in turn shadowing the earlier cabal. Why is this happening?

```
$ ghc -v Main.hs 
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.8.4, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.8.4
Using binary package database: /usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/package.cache
hiding package Cabal-1.18.1.5 to avoid conflict with later version Cabal-1.22.1.1
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.3.1.0-ec14d2f6075975a2ce9112eae431c8e1
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-0.5.1.0-de4898ebdc5ab81cedce89121ae9ac84
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.7.0.2-5ef1e7e809bc3b18d74efc783356e209
wired-in package rts mapped to builtin_rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.9.0.0-c1976a420ad8b9b589eee08844c59ba2
wired-in package dph-seq not found.
wired-in package dph-par not found.
Hsc static flags: 
hiding package Cabal-1.18.1.5 to avoid conflict with later version Cabal-1.22.1.1
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.3.1.0-ec14d2f6075975a2ce9112eae431c8e1
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-0.5.1.0-de4898ebdc5ab81cedce89121ae9ac84
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.7.0.2-5ef1e7e809bc3b18d74efc783356e209
wired-in package rts mapped to builtin_rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.9.0.0-c1976a420ad8b9b589eee08844c59ba2
wired-in package dph-seq not found.
wired-in package dph-par not found.
*** Chasing dependencies:
Chasing modules from: *Main.hs

Main.hs:3:8:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Natural’
    Locations searched:
    Data/Natural.hs
    Data/Natural.lhs
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: 
*** Deleting temp dirs:
Deleting:
```

Comment: did you update your .cabal file?

Comment: @Sigrlami I'm afraid I don't understand. I have a directory called `$HOME/.cabal` and `/tmp/haskell-example/.cabal-sandbox`, but no `.cabal` file. What would I need to do to update it?

Comment: When you're using command `cabal init` inside your project is creating `foo.cabal` file which describes all needed dependencies, and you need to add them manually. Assuming your project name `foo`.For example, https://github.com/sigrlami/pollock/blob/master/pollock.cabal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're into manual hacking, you can pass to ghc the sandbox's pkg db location, such as:

```
ghc Main.hs -package-db .cabal-sandbox/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.2-packages.conf.d/
```

However the "normal" way to use sandboxes is to always compile using `cabal build` (or `cabal install` with no parameters) rather than running ghc directly.

1. Run `cabal init`, answer questions as you please
2. Edit the resulting `foo.cabal` file (`foo` is the name of your package).
3. Run `cabal build` or `cabal install` - this will run ghc for you.

When editing the cabal file, check that your exported modules (if it's a lib) are listed and that your main src is correct. Also make sure dependencies such as `natural-numbers` are listed in the `build-depends:` clause.

Comment: Wait a second. I think I was thinking about `cabal` completely the wrong way. I was expecting a cabal sandbox to behave like a virtualenv or npm environment and alter behavior of ghc, but it seems like the only similarity is that it redirects where `cabal install` installs things. This makes so much sense now.